# Obtaining DataSource from Cayenne DataConext

Tags: java, jdbc, orm, apache-cayenne

Currently I am using Cayenne as my ORM. I need to get DataSource for initializing Velocity Engine in my code. I can manually create the datasource but I don't want to do it and want to use the existing datasource from Cayenne.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cayenne 3.1 it is rather trivial:

```
ServerRuntime runtime = .. // this exists in every app
DataSource ds = runtime.getDataSource("MyDataNode");
```

In the earlier versions it is only marginally harder:

```
DataDomain dd = context.getParentDataDomain();
DataSource ds = dd.getDataNode("MyDataNode").getDataSource();
```

The last approach works on 3.1 too BTW.

Comment: As Cayenne 3.1 is still in Beta phase I am using 3.0 version. And Thanks for your answer. It worked for me.